# Project compiles but not displaying info in compiler

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

Hey I'm making a program that takes words+definitions from a text document, scrambles them, then quizzes you on them. The words are structured as (word: definition).
 I finished the code for the project but for some reason the console stays blank after I compile.
 The code consists of three classes that I'll display below:

**Class 1 :-**

```
public class VocabularyWord {
    private String word, definition;

public VocabularyWord(String w, String d){
    word=w;
    definition=d;
}
public String getDefinition(){
    return definition;
}
public String getWord(){
    return word;
}
public String toString(){
    return word+" "+definition;
}
}
```

**Class 2 :-**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VocabularyTest {
private ArrayList<VocabularyWord>words;
private int c;

public VocabularyTest() throws FileNotFoundException{
    words=new ArrayList<VocabularyWord>();
    ArrayList<String> str=new ArrayList<String>();
    File inputFile = new File("Vocabulary.txt");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        str.add(input.nextLine());
        processStrings(str);
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
            swapWords();
}
}
private void processStrings(ArrayList<String>lines){
    int pos=0;
    for(int i=lines.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
        pos=lines.get(i).indexOf(":");
        String s=lines.get(i).substring(0, pos);
        String ss=lines.get(i).substring(pos+1, lines.get(i).length());
        VocabularyWord p=new VocabularyWord(s,ss);
        words.add(p);
        c++;
    }
}
private void swapWords(){
    int x=(int) (Math.random()*words.size());
    int xx=(int)(Math.random()*words.size());
    while(x==xx)
        xx=(int)(Math.random()*words.size());
    Collections.swap(words, xx, x);
    }
public void quiz(){
    System.out.println("hi");
    int n=0;
    Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=words.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
        System.out.println(words.get(i).getDefinition());
            if(kb.nextLine().equals(words.get(i).getWord())){
                System.out.println("Nice Job!");
                n++;
            }
            else
                System.out.println(words.get(i).getWord());
    }
    System.out.println("You got "+n+" correct!");
}

}
```

**Class 3 :-**

```
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 public class VocabTestTester {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException{
        VocabularyTest test= new VocabularyTest();
        test.quiz();

        }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's time to debug your program. You state, `"the console stays blank after I compile..."` -- do you actually **run** the program after compiling it?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say compile and run.

Comment: **How** are you running it?

Comment: Pressing the run icon in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your VocabularyTest constructor is failing, possibly that you're not finding the file adequately, although I'd expect to see an exception from this. You'd do well to check this.

Print "hi" on the first line of the VocabularyTest constructor, print out the file path, **and check that it matches the path that you expect**, and then print out the words read in to the console.

e.g.,

```
public VocabularyTest() throws FileNotFoundException{
    System.out.println("In VocabularTest Constructor");
    words=new ArrayList<VocabularyWord>();
    ArrayList<String> str=new ArrayList<String>();
    File inputFile = new File("Vocabulary.txt");

    System.out.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());

    Scanner input = new Scanner(inputFile);
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
        System.out.println(input.nextLin());
    }
```

Comment: F*** yeah found error in constructor. Closed while loop and then we were good. Thanks man, have a good night (if in North America)!